# Accessing Mac property files via C

Tags: c, macos, plist

I am accessing a plist file using the code below on a Cocoa with Objective-C application:

```
NSString *plistPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *item = [plistData valueForKeyPath:@"MailAccounts.AccountName"];
NSLog(@"Account: %@", [item objectAtIndex:2]);
```

Which essentially returns the email address of the user (we also read some other information on other plist files) so we can add it to the About dialog.

I need now to read this information from the same plist files using `C`, not `Objective-C`. The files are not text, they are binary encoded plist files. Is there any way to read those property files from C?

Can I call `NSDictionary` etc from C? How?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you realize that Objective C is an extension of C, but in general, when I'm using plain ol' C, I use Core Foundation functions and objects instead of Objective C methods.

To your specific question: CFDictionary is toll-free bridged to NSDictionary and CFBundle to NSBundle.  You can easily call CoreFoundation from plain ol' C.

You can get what you want with something like:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFDictionaryRef dictionaryRef = CFBundleGetInfoDictionary(mainBundle);
if(dictionaryRef)
{
    CFArrayRef accountsItemsArrayRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(dictionaryRef, CFSTR("MailAccounts.AccountName");
    if(accountsItemsArrayRef)
    {
         CFStringRef accountNameRef = (CFStringRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(accountsItemsArrayRef, 2);
         if(accountNameRef)
         {
               fprintf(stderr, "Account: %s", accountName.cStr());
         }       
    }
}
```

I just typed this Core Foundation translation directly into this answer box and did no error or sanity checking, which you absolutely would need to do.

[Here is a slightly older tutorial](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BridgingForFunAndProfit) that explains a bit more.

Hope this helps to get you on the right path!

Comment: Great, let me try it. BTW, do you want what should I `#include`?

Comment: yep... I made a code typo there.  Use `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex` to get the value at an index.  I corrected my code in the answer above.

Comment: Ok, got it. Still not able to access `CFStringRef` cStr() doesn't exits... The documentation doesn't help me here. Would you mind telling me what should I include? I am currently including `CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h` and `CoreServices/CoreServices.h` but no luck.

Comment: so I solved it by doing `char* str = CFStringGetCStringPtr(accountNameRef, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);` In any case, it's empty. How does loading the main bundle gives me access to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`?

Comment: You're right, the convenience functions for creating the dictionary from the main bundle doesn't help you in this case.  Unfortunately, loading CFDictionaryRef from a plist file is ***not*** the most trivial thing, but it can be done.  Apple provides handy sample code in their ["Saving & Restoring a Property List in Core Foundation" documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH7-SW5) (look at Listing 5-3).

Comment: I guess... That sample just writes a `plain text` property's file. I've been trying to convert that code to be able to read a `binary` plist list but no joy... I guess it can't be done, huh?

Comment: Why do you think it can't be done?  I see a `CreateMyPropertyListFromFile` function at the bottom of that listing I pointed you to. It should also work for binary plists.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it but every time I try to read a binary plist it just crashes or returns empty nothing. So, unless I am missing something, and it's a huge possibility, I cannot do it with the way you, apple's example and other sources I've found. I wish for once someone could just write a small snippet that does solve the question I ask and not point to other websites saying "look at x function" or x API. If I am asking is because I don't know and i continue not knowing after breaking my head trying to figure examples that do not really apply to my problem.

Comment: Well... I did try to help point you to ways to get to the finish line. If every option you're being thrown just isn't working for you, perhaps you should consider another approach (e.g. don't use C or CoreFoundation, stick with Objective C).  Maybe somebody else will come up with a better answer for you.  Or, if you do figure out the answer yourself, definitely post a publicly available "load CFDictionaryFromFile" method which will help other folks down the road.  Good luck!

Comment: That I will if I ever get around this. I wish config files were plain text like good old unix. Thanks for the help.